# how can I prune a rrd file by date

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Hello is there a way to prune a rrd file by date? It seems posible as `rrdtool dump file` dumps

```
<!-- 2012-05-07 19:15:00 UTC / 1336418100 --> <row><v> 0.0000000000e+00 </v></row>
<!-- 2012-05-07 19:20:00 UTC / 1336418400 --> <row><v> 9.6589767000e-01 </v></row>
<!-- 2012-05-07 19:25:00 UTC / 1336418700 --> <row><v> 3.4568563333e-02 </v></row>
<!-- 2012-05-07 19:30:00 UTC / 1336419000 --> <row><v> 9.6402870667e-01 </v></row>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the dump file prior to restore ... not sure what you mean by pruning, since rrdfiles always stay the same size.

Comment: i mean i have some data in a monthly network usage bad measured, and it hurts to my statistics, I can't wait to get rotate a monthly or a yearly rrd file

Comment: there is a flag for rrdtool restore which will turn any data into *UNKNOWN* that is outside the configured min and max ... you can edit the min and max with rrdtool tune.